# Firebase analytics: maximum number of event names?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I wonder what is the maximum number of event names that can be recorded in Firebase Analytics when calling the following:

```
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("eventName1", params);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("eventName2", params);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("eventameX", params);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can report up to 500 different types of Events per app and you can associate up to 25 unique parameters with each Event type.

If you already reached the limit, then the extra events will be dropped. A firebase_error event is logged with a firebase_error parameter which indicates the error code.

See the following documentations for more information:

- [FirebaseAnalytics.Event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event)
- [Analytics Error Codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/errors)

Comment: Thanks. Note : first link is corrupted.

Comment: Do you know if this limit can be upgraded with a paid plan? I can't seem to find any info about it on the Firebase documentation.

Comment: Limits can't be upgraded. `https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9237506?hl=en`

Comment: How all these five hundred events are differentiated ? Based on the parameter combination used in creating an event of anything else. Please help here

Comment: They are differentiated based on the event name.  Parameters are not taken into account.